# PHP Netbeans project on localhost not working on nginx server, opens nginx welcome page every time?

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans, nginx, localhost

I'm trying to run my PHP project through netbeans using the nginx server on localhost, although every time I debug it the page that opens is the nginx welcome page (to say that it is up and running)

In the run configuration it is set as

```
"Local Web Site(running on local web server)"
```

And the Project URL is set as

```
  "http://localhost:80/"
```

Im running Netbeans 7.4 on Ubuntu 13.10

Any insight would be muchos appreciated

Comment: Try on Xaamp or Wampserver.

Comment: I would but it has to be nginx, thanks anyway !

Comment: where did you upload your website on the server? what is the path ?, also what distro is the server ?

Comment: I didn't upload anywhere on the server , its stored locally in "/home/user/NetBeansProjects/DemoPHP" , nginx version is 1.4.6